# is there a web app for returning results to a search on an indexed database?

Tags: web, file-server, locate

I would very much like to allow users in a small office environment harness the power of `slocate` indexed database on the file server.
Currently when users are looking for a file in our fileserver, they need to run `find` from their Windows workstations on the network shares that are available from the server. **This loads up the server while other are working.**

Alternatively, I could set the indexers in every workstation to index the server locations. This is not ideal either, as the server would again be loaded a task that must be **run multiple times a day on the same set of data**!

Ideally, the file server will carry out its own indexing and my users (who are oblivious to Linux and its command-line) will be able to log on to a simple website on the file server and run a search in much the same way I run `locate` commands in the command line.

Is there something available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked and did not find any offering that provided just a web app interface to an existing `slocate` database file.

So you have the following options:

1. Roll your own. Shouldn't be too difficult use a CGI based approach which would allow users to search for entries in your pre-built `slocate` database file.
2. Skip using the `slocate` database file and use a dedicated search engine such as one of the following that includes both a crawler and a web frontend:

   - [OpenSearchServer](http://www.open-search-server.com/)
   - [Hyper Estraier](http://fallabs.com/hyperestraier/intro-en.html)
   - [Recoll](http://www.lesbonscomptes.com/recoll/) + [Recoll-WebUI](https://github.com/koniu/recoll-webui)
   - [Wumpus Search Engine](http://www.wumpus-search.org/)